# What does undeclared identifier and identifier is undefined mean? How to fix the error?

Tags: c++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define TIMEQUANTUM 1;
#define MAXPROCTIME 100;


struct SortList
{
    int pid;
    int arrivalTime;
    int burstTime;
    SortList *nxt;
};

struct JobList {
    int pid;
    int ct_arrival;
    int ct_service;
    int vt_served;
    int vt_residence;
    int vt_wait;
    int vt_completion;
    JobList *nxt;
};



bool initJobList(JobList *&,int *,int);
bool deinit(JobList *&);
bool doFCFS (JobList *&);
bool doRR (JobList *&);
bool doSJF(JobList *&, SortList *&);
bool doNPSJF (JobList *&);
bool doPSJF (JobList *&);
bool sortJob (JobList *&, SortList *&);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    JobList *ptrJobStart;
    // arrivaltime , bursttime
    int arrJobs[][2] = {
                        {0,7},
                        {2,4},
                        {4,1},
                        {5,4}
    };   
    SortList *ptrList;
    initJobList (ptrJobStart,(int *)&arrJobs, (sizeof(arrJobs) / (sizeof(int)*2)));
    printf("\ndoFCFS\nCPU\t\tPROCESS\n");
       doFCFS (ptrJobStart);
    deinit(ptrJobStart);

    initJobList (ptrJobStart,(int *)&arrJobs, (sizeof(arrJobs) / (sizeof(int)*2)));
    printf("\n\ndoSJF\nCPU\t\tPROCESS\n");
        doSJF(ptrJobStart, ptrList);
    deinit(ptrJobStart);


    initJobList (ptrJobStart,(int *)&arrJobs, (sizeof(arrJobs) / (sizeof(int)*2)));
    printf("\ndoRR\nCPU\t\tPROCESS\n");
    doRR(ptrJobStart);
    deinit(ptrJobStart);

    initJobList (ptrJobStart,(int *)&arrJobs, (sizeof(arrJobs) / (sizeof(int)*2)));
    printf("\ndoPSJF\nCPU\t\tPROCESS\n");
    doRR(ptrJobStart);
    deinit(ptrJobStart);

    getch();
    return 0;   
}

bool doRR(JobList *&ptrJobStart)
{


    if(ptrJob==NULL) return false;
    JobList *ptrJobStart, *tempJobList;
    ptrJobStart = ptrJob;
    int maxTime = MAXPROCTIME;
    int timeQuantum = TIMEQUANTUM;
    bool flag = false;
    ptrJobStart->vt_served = 0;
    for(int processTime = 0; (processTime < maxTime) && !flag ;)
    {
        //check if all jobs are finished
        flag = true;
        tempJobList = ptrJob;
        while(tempJobList!=NULL)
        {
            if(tempJobList->vt_served!=tempJobList->ct_service)
            {
                flag = false;
            }
            tempJobList = tempJobList->nxt;
        }
    }
    //logic
    return true;
}

bool doSJF(JobList *&ptrJobStart, SortList *&ptrList)
{
    if(ptrJobStart==NULL) return false;
    sortJob(ptrJobStart, ptrList); 
    doFCFS (ptrJobStart);
    return true;
}

bool sortJob (JobList *&ptrJob, SortList *&ptrList)
{
    JobList *ptrJobStart = ptrJob;
    if(ptrJobStart==NULL) return false;
    int maxTime = MAXPROCTIME;
    SortList *newList;
    ptrList = NULL;
    for(; ptrJobStart!=NULL; ptrJobStart = ptrJobStart->nxt) // accumulate all arrival time = 0
    {
        if(ptrJobStart->ct_arrival==0)
        {
            if(ptrList==NULL)
            {
                ptrList = new SortList;
                ptrList->pid = ptrJobStart->pid;
                ptrList->arrivalTime = ptrJobStart->ct_arrival;
                ptrList->burstTime = ptrJobStart->ct_service;
                ptrList->nxt = NULL;
            }
            else
            {
                newList = new SortList;
                newList->pid = ptrJobStart->pid;
                newList->arrivalTime = ptrJobStart->ct_arrival;
                newList->burstTime = ptrJobStart->ct_service;
                newList->nxt = NULL;
                ptrList->nxt = newList;
            }
        }
    }
    SortList *tempList;
    tempList = ptrList;
    for(int processTime = 1 ; processTime < maxTime ; processTime++) // accumulate all burst time from 1 to 100
    {
        ptrJobStart = ptrJob;
        do
        {
            if((ptrJobStart->ct_arrival!=0) && (processTime == ptrJobStart->ct_service))
            {
                newList = new SortList;
                newList->pid = ptrJobStart->pid;
                newList->arrivalTime = ptrJobStart->ct_arrival;
                newList->burstTime = ptrJobStart->ct_service;
                newList->nxt = NULL;
                tempList->nxt = newList;
                tempList = tempList->nxt;
            }
            ptrJobStart = ptrJobStart->nxt;
        }while(ptrJobStart!=NULL);
    }
    //sort jobs
    ptrJobStart = ptrJob;
    JobList *tempJobList;
    tempJobList = ptrJobStart;
    for(; ptrList!=NULL; ptrList = ptrList->nxt)
    {
        tempJobList->pid = ptrList->pid;
        tempJobList->ct_arrival = ptrList->arrivalTime;
        tempJobList->ct_service = ptrList->burstTime;
        tempJobList = tempJobList->nxt;
    }
    return true;
}


bool doFCFS (JobList *& ptrJob)
{
    JobList *ptrJobStart = ptrJob;
    if(ptrJobStart==NULL) return false;
    int maxTime = MAXPROCTIME;
    ptrJobStart->vt_served = 0;
    for(int processTime = 0; processTime < maxTime; processTime++)
    {
        if(ptrJobStart->vt_served!=ptrJobStart->ct_service)
        {
            ptrJobStart->vt_served+=1;
        }
        else
        {
            ptrJobStart->vt_completion = processTime;
            ptrJobStart->vt_residence = processTime - ptrJobStart->ct_arrival;
            ptrJobStart->vt_wait = processTime - ptrJobStart->vt_served;
            cout<<"\n/* vt_served:"<<ptrJobStart->vt_served<<"\tvt_residence:"<<ptrJobStart->vt_residence
                <<"\tvt_wait:"<<ptrJobStart->vt_wait<<"\tvt_completion:"<<ptrJobStart->vt_completion<<" */";
            ptrJobStart = ptrJobStart->nxt;
            if(ptrJobStart==NULL) break;
            else
                ptrJobStart->vt_served = 1;
        }
        cout<<"\n "<<processTime<<"\t>>\t P"<<ptrJobStart->pid;
    }
    return true;
}


bool deinit (JobList *& ptrJobStart) {

    JobList *ptrJobDel = NULL;
    do {

        ptrJobDel = ptrJobStart;
        ptrJobStart = ptrJobStart->nxt;
        delete ptrJobDel;
    }while (ptrJobStart != NULL);
    return true;
}


bool initJobList(JobList*& ptrJobStart,int *pJob,int nJobs){

    JobList * ptrJobs = NULL;
    int i;
    int j=1;

    for (i=0; i<nJobs*2; i+=2) {
        if (ptrJobs == NULL) {
            ptrJobs = new JobList;
            memset(ptrJobs,0,sizeof(JobList));
            ptrJobStart = ptrJobs;
        }
        else {
            ptrJobs->nxt = new JobList;
            memset(ptrJobs->nxt,0,sizeof(JobList));
            ptrJobs = ptrJobs->nxt;
        }
        ptrJobs->ct_arrival = *(pJob+i);
        ptrJobs->ct_service = *(pJob+(i+1));
        ptrJobs->pid = j;
        ptrJobs->nxt = NULL;
        j++;
    }
    return true;
```

This code is for the scheduling algorithm. The shortest Job Next(SJN) / Shortest Job First (SJF) (which is the doSJN) is working. But when I included the doRR (do Round Robin), there are a lot of errors occuring.

error C2065: 'ptrJob' : undeclared identifier
error C2082: redefinition of formal parameter 'ptrJobStart
error C2065: 'ptrJob' : undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'ptrJob' : undeclared identifier
see declaration of 'getch'

How can i fix this?

Comment: Do you know what the terms "identifier" and "declaration" mean? Can you spot instances of both in the code?

Answer (score 1):

In `doRR`, the argument is named `ptrJobStart`. It should be `ptrJob` instead.

The error you got states that on the first line of `doRR`, `ptrJob` has not been declared.

Comment: thank you. that helps. but another thing, there is no output. the output for the doRR is blank. why is that?

Comment: What do you mean by "the output is blank" ?

Comment: The output of each process must include processes and the number of jobs done.. unlike for the part of doRR, it doesnt give anything.

Comment: this is the screenshot for the displayed output

Answer (score 1):

The first error (redefinition of formal parameter 'ptrJobStar') occurs here:

```
bool doRR(JobList *&ptrJobStart)
{


    if(ptrJob==NULL) return false;
    JobList *ptrJobStart, *tempJobList;
```

You're defining a parameter ptrJobStart, then declaring the same-named parameter in the code.

I *believe* the second error ('ptrJob': Undeclared identifier) occurs here:

```
bool doRR(JobList *&ptrJobStart)
{


    if(ptrJob==NULL) return false;
```

That's because 'ptrJob' doesn't appear to be declared within doRR().

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes. but i got another problem. if i could just post here the screenshot of my output.